# How to prove: If $\textsf{EXP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly} $ then $\textsf{EXP} = \Sigma^p_2$

Tags: complexity-theory, nondeterminism

Following is a theorem from Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak I am unable to prove :

> If $\textsf{EXP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$ then $\textsf{EXP} = \Sigma^p_2$.

The previous similar theorem was

> If $\textsf{NP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$ then $\textsf{PH}=\Sigma_2^p$.

The second theorem was easy to prove  as $\textsf{NP}=\Sigma_1^p$. But $\textsf{EXP}$ does not have such characteristic. How do I prove the first theorem. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more classical statement is that if $\textsf{EXP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$ then $\textsf{EXP} = \textsf{MA}$, due to [Babai, Fortnow and Lund](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/mip2.pdf). [Impagliazzo, Kabanets and Wigderson](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IKW02/IKW02.pdf) showed that $\textsf{NEXP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$ iff $\textsf{NEXP} = \textsf{MA}$. See [lecture notes of Bogdanov](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/courses/f07-80240233/notes/lec15.pdf) for proof sketches.

Answer (score 5):

There is a more 'elementary' proof of the problem that doesn't involve the polynomial-encoding/self-correction ideas of BFL.  The result appears in the original Karp-Lipton paper and is credited to Meyer.  The way I think of it is like this:

Step 1: Show that EXP in P/poly implies EXP = PSPACE.  Hints: Show that if M is an EXP-machine, the entries of the computation tableau of M(x) are computable from x in EXP.  Conclude that they're computable in P/poly.  Now in PSPACE, try all circuits, and check that all entries of the tableau are locally correct.

Step 2: Show that PSPACE in P/poly implies PSPACE = Sigma_2.  Hints: Similarly, the tableau-contents-function of a PSPACE machine is in PSPACE, hence in P/poly.  Now in Sigma_2, you can nondeterministically guess a circuit supposedly computing the tableau, and then conondeterministically verify its correctness.

Step 3: Combine Steps 2 and 3 together.

Comment: Why does 2 not hold directly for EXP?